# It is feasible to generate client-side scripts on the server in realtime?

Tags: javascript, rest, client-server

I'm working on an application where there are a number of available resources that differ on an hour-by-hour basis, and loading all permutations in the client would result in a very, very large script.

I'm strongly considering having the server dynamically generate a minified script combining all currently optimal resources, preloaded with configuration and user-specific credentials (only loaded if logged in, of course), in realtime. The script isn't needed until after the user interacts with the page, so it can safely be loaded client-side with `defer` allowing the server the milliseconds it needs to do its thing, and round trip time on the network. I've considered that this does prevent caching the script, and I'm not sure this is a problem given how it's currently built. In other words, something like this:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="/dynamically-generated-script.js"></script>
```

I figured this is the perfect type of question to ask the community here at Stack Overflow, given I've never tried realtime dynamic script generation like this, and I could definitely see it being a tried and tested (and possibly failed) practice that I'm just not aware of.

Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's feasible, but i would strongly recommend against it for the following reasons:

- Once the script is dynamically generated, you will lose many layers of optimizations, starting from the browser caching the script, and up to hosting the script on a CDN.
- The fact that the script can not be cached means that you are moving away from the most recent trends of Web development:  progressive web apps (PWA), and Accelerated mobile pages (AMP)
- Error handling from the client side become an extremely hard issue, because basically you have a script for each user. error reporting services like sentry, will not be able to identify identical errors (since each error will be generated from a different file)
- Security, performance, and even general code quality will be hard to measure and control, since again you have an extremely large number of different code.
- You wont be able to do any static analysis on these generated files, so you lose access to many of the tools that help developers write better code - you may still be able to do static analysis on the code that generates these dynamic scripts, however that is another thing.
- Analytics on usage might also suffer, depending on how advanced the analytics that you wanna do.

All that being said, i would strongly consider other solutions. I dont know the exact requirements, so its hard to tell exactly, however i noticed two things:

- You said that you wanna move credentials and configurations to the client side, this is a bad practice, even if the customer need a large diverse number of configurations and credentials - especially credentials. These should be saved on the server side, and can be accessed by the client side once client is authorised based on one credential -usually a token stored in cookies. You may say i need these credentials to do some requests from the client to 3rd party services, if that is  the case then you should be doing these requests from your server side, and the client should be calling the server side instead of calling these 3rd party services directly.
- code is often not a dynamic thing, because code itself enables you to do control flow - its the data that the code interacts with that is often dynamic. What  i'm trying to say here is that it is hard to imagine requirements that makes you need different code for each different user - in some cases you may want to have different versions of code but that is a different thing.

To expand upon the previous point, i think the solution to your problem, is that you load the script that has all the code that is needed, and then based on different conditions you execute certain paths of code. You may still want to load dynamic data based on dynamic conditions and this can be done by calling the server. Even if u really had to do certain functionality that is truly dynamic for each user, then such functionality should be exposed behind an api that will be called from the client.

Comment: I greatly appreciate many of the points in the first half of the answer, many of which I hadn't considered (like the error handling and performance measurement bits, which fell entirely outside my consideration somehow). However, a few points for the second half. First, when I said "credentials," I was referring to client-side credentials, which must arrive at the client at some point regardless in order to access third-party services which, due to strict performance constraints, are not practical to proxy through the server. Second, much of the optimization is for the same speed constraint...

Comment: ...Ultimately, the problem is that there are dozens of third-party services that _could_ need to be accessed by the client, which are very, very heavily optimized by their providers such that they can feasibly be accessed quickly by client-side scripts. Each comes with its own minified client-side library, but these are several kilobytes each, and loading them all would be quite expensive. So the optimization leading into this admittedly strange decision is to pick and choose which of these services will actually be necessary for a given user, and only serve the client-side libraries for those